# GoogleMap composable taking all available screen space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I expected the following code to show The map on the top and two text fields at the bottom. Instead, the map is taking all available space.

[image: Map Picture]

```kotlin
Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),

        ) {
        
        GoogleMap(
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
        ) {
            Marker(
                position = singapore,
                title = "Singapore",
                snippet = "Marker in Singapore"
            )
        }

        TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = "Load Location") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = "Unload Location") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
```

Comment: Modifier.weight(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever heard of the `weight` modifier?

Comment: Wait a minute...